# bignum multiplication in SBCL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Yesterday I tried to figure out the size of the new Mersenne Prime (http://www.mersenne.org/primes/?press=M74207281)
on my SBCL box (v. 1.3.2 (x64), Windows 10, Dell Core i5 8GB RAM)
After almost one hour I gave up and interrupted the calculation.
Below the resulting screen:

```
This is SBCL 1.3.2, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.

WARNING: the Windows port is fragile, particularly for multithreaded
code.  Unfortunately, the development team currently lacks the time
and resources this platform demands.
* (- (expt 2 74207281) 1)


debugger invoked on a SB-SYS:INTERACTIVE-INTERRUPT in thread
 '#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002A9BD03}>:'
  Interactive interrupt at #x100008BD9E.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):

  0: [CONTINUE] Return from SB-WIN32::SIGINT.

  1: [ABORT   ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
1

(SB-BIGNUM:MULTIPLY-BIGNUMS #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument>)
0] 1
```

To me this was interesting, because I tried the same expression on Racket 6.4, on the same machine,
And it took (comparatively) only 1m08s to start spitting numbers.
In Haskell, again on the same machine, with

```
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

Prelude> 2^74207281 - 1
```

it took only 8s to start the numbers' exhibition.

Despite the fact that it could be a bug, do anyone know how SBCL do bignum multiplication? Would its way of doing it be the possible cause of delay?

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT**

After Sylvester´s comment, maybe the right question is: What is preventing the big number from been shown? Yes, it is really big (Racket and Haskell versions wrote it to a text file of 21 MB), but it seems that there is something more than its size preventing the task´s completion.

Comment: Sylwester's answer is the right one: bignum multiplication is quick, but *printing* is slow.  Printing very large numbers has been a performance problem in a number of systems (mostly Lisps, but not only): I suspect that the obvious way to do it has some horrible performance characteristics, but there clearly is some better approach as witnessed by Racket &c.  One question would be to time the complete process (to a file, not the terminal!): it might be that the better systems *start* emitting digits sooner but take similar or perhaps even more time to generate the whole output.

Comment: `74207281 * log10(2) = 22338617.47766583040356636` => 22338618 million digits, few first of which are 30037641... (*`10 ** 0.47766583040356636 = 3.003764155059042`*).

Comment: @ tfb: do you have a clue how to do this? The standard approach (open - write-line - close) lead to the same.

Comment: @ Will Ness: yes, you are right: the big file I've got with Racket starts with 30037641...

Comment: @rand: if that's the case then I guess SBCL's bignum printing really is slow, and the answer would be to look at what it does that makes it so slow.  Which is not really a useful answer, of course.  It's just possible that turning off some of the print-prettily options might help.

Answer (score 6):

The actual calculation is pretty fast on my machine, less than a second in fact.

```lisp
(defun make-prime ()
  (declare (optimize (safety 0)(debug 0)(speed 3)))
  (time (- (expt 2 74207281) 1)))

(defparameter *prime* (make-prime))

;Evaluation took:
;  0.000 seconds of real time
;  0.000017 seconds of total run time (0.000015 user, 0.000002 system)
;  100.00% CPU
;  1,292 processor cycles
;  0 bytes consed
; ==> *PRIME*
```

However printing the number is a whole other matter.

Comment: I´ve tried your code, witch took almost the same time, but when I execute (make-prime) the print hung up again. I was driven to think that the problem was the bignum multiplication (SB-BIGNUM:MULTIPLY-BIGNUMS), I will rephrase my question.